# UITextView change textColor weird behaviour

Tags: ios, xcode, text, colors, uitextview

I have a UITextView added to my main view. I am able to type things in it. But when i change the font color programatically (by tapping on a UIButton), the bottom part of the text color is not changed (as you can see in the photo attached).

Code in a IBAction of button:

```
 [myTextView setTextColor:clr];
```

[image]

Why is this happening and how can I fix it? I tried [myTextView setNeedsDisplay]; doesn't work.

Comment: what's the architecture of your components ? views, buttons, textView order please.

Comment: there is just uitextview and a delete "X" button there. uitextview at the bottom and X button at top. that is all. the button to change color is elsewhere